# iOS - Background Transfer Service for Auto Update data at fixed intervel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am developing an app of feeds, that fetches feed from server and display to users for read. It working fine when app starts but i want to load data in background when is suspended or terminate(in both case). As we can create IntentService in android and with a AlarmManager we can start that service after a every fixed hours (for ex. 3 hours), so whenever user comes to online he will be able to see latest data without waiting fetch for new feeds.

I have read Background Transfer Service & `NSURLSession` with silent remote notification but i could not understand how this will help me to achieve my objective.

When getting a remote notification how can i resume a `NSURLSessionDataTask` form `AppDelegate.m` file because we can't use delegate there.

Please help me to sort out this issue. Googling from last 2 days but didn't get success to achieve this.

Comment: Have you checked this tut http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch--mobile-20520

Comment: ..or also have a look here: https://github.com/lcbullock/iOS7-Background-Transfer-Service

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Background Fetch](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/) instead of Background Transfer. Main purpose of Background Transfer is uploading or downloading files while when app in background state.